# Does "there are" pronounce /ðer/ in spoken American?

Tags: colloquial-language

[An American tutorial teaches reduced speaking](https://youtu.be/FStyKn4V8cE?t=765), where "there are" sounds like /ðer/, am I hearing correctly? Do Americans speak that way in real life?

Comment: This sounds to me more like /'ðerer/.

Comment: @user34258 You really listened to that part, and then gave that response, right? If yes, thank you!

Comment: I did listen to it. She says it very quickly, especially the first time, but that's what I hear. It's also a normal thing to hear in American English.